# Snowflake merge into on delete is either deleting everything or keeping all rows?

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I am having this merge into script:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP_TABLE_NAME ST USING (
    SELECT
        SOBS.OBSERVATION_DATE_LOCATION_HASH_KEY AS HASH_KEY,
        SOBS.LOAD_END_DT AS DELETION_TIME
    FROM
        SAT_OBSERVATION SOBS
    WHERE
        SOBS.LOAD_END_DT IS NOT NULL
) ON md5(
    CONCAT(
        DATE(ST.OBSERVATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
        CONCAT('CAMP', CONCAT(ST.CAMPNO, ST._SUBMISSION_TIME))
    )
) = HASH_KEY
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE ";
```

This script will look into a table called `SAT_OBSERVATION` for an existing `HASH_KEY` and delete all existing hash keys in the `TEMP_TABLE_NAME`.

The problem with this script is that it is not deleting rows. It either keeps everything, or delete all rows if I removed the part `WHERE SOBS.LOAD_END_DT IS NOT NULL`.

I tried it with `WHERE SOBS.LOAD_END_DT IS NULL` and all rows in the temp table has been deleted.

Let's say we have 3 rows into the temp table, and 2 out of these rows HASH_KEYs already exists, I need to keep only one row in the temp.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that Merge statement (apart from the two apostrophes next to DELETE which I presume is just a typo). By the look of it the column  SOBS.LOAD_END_DT is always NULL. I would encourage you to write a SELECT statement that joins the two tables so that you can see what would actually be deleted by the Merge.

Comment: You might have nondeterministic results for your DELETE and that would cause undesired results. See more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior)

Comment: `WHERE SOBS.LOAD_END_DT` is the partvis not working. SOBS is a permanent table so I think the `ON` CLAUSE is not taking the proper hash keys to be deleted from its table.